# TPMS sensor replacement in 2010 Prius

Tags: toyota, prius, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

I have a 2010 Toyota Prius and one or more of the factory tire pressure monitoring system (TPMS) sensors have failed (probably due to age) and I want to replace them with (cheaper) aftermarket sensors from Amazon.

I purchased aftermarket sensors, and the two repair shops I went to could not link the sensors to the car (Pep Boys and an independent tire store.)  They indicated that for many cars, you can link them to the car using a handheld programming tool. However, they said this did not work with that Prius.

How can I link the new sensors to the computer in the Prius?

Answer (score 2):

You must use the Toyota Techstream software on a Windows PC connected to the ODB port on the Prius, via a USB cable.

1. Make a note of the ID numbers for each TPMS sensor.  They're hex codes, and in my case were seven digits long.  They're printed on a label on each sensor.
2. Acquire a Mini VCI J2534 Cable, which is an ODB II to USB cable.  I purchased on ebay.
3. Acquire Windows computer with a copy of the Toyota Techstream software. I tested with version 17.x installed on Windows 10 64-bit.  A copy of the software came with the cable. I installed it on a feshly installed, non-internet connected Windows 10 64-bit laptop.  I followed the procedure that came with the software.
4. **Turn the car on**, then connect the J2534 cable from the PC to the Prius ODB II port and start the Techstream software. If the car is in accessory mode, or not turned on, the software will load but many functions will not be available.
5. In Techstream, go to the System Selection menu and select Tire Pressure Monitor and click Next.
6. Then go to Utility, and select ID Registration.
7. There are five slots for the TPMS codes, 4 tires plus a spare.  Enter the code for each sensor and complete the process.  It seems you can enter 0000000 for the spare if you don't want to program its code.
8. In Techstream Tire Pressure Monitor, go to Data List. It will display the registered codes for each sensor, and the current pressure reading.

[image: Mini VCI J2534]
[image: TPWS sensor code]